# Display 4-space indent as 2-space in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

Is it possible without any code modification? Making a tab would insert 4 spaces, but in editor it would look like 2. I think it might be useful to display code from different libraries with the same indent size.

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite of this. Please be sure to update the question if you ever find an answer! :)

Comment: In 2023 they added a "virtual formatter" to ReSharper, which does exactly that, so something similar might be coming for IntelliJ IDEA in the not so distant future.

Answer (score 0):

No. How could 4 spaces could look like 2? Only a Tab can look like any number of spaces.

Comment: Treat every 4 spaces as 2-space tab in the editor, but write 4 spaces to file.

Comment: This is the reason to use tabs as your indents - it is then up to the user and his client to choose what width it is :)

Comment: Unless your company has already decreed two spaces, and you'd prefer it to be configurable

Comment: How is this even an answer?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf What else would you want?